# PHP move checker pieces inside multi-dimensional array part 2

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I already have the pieces mapped out in the array and it prints just fine

```
    $board = array(
             array('1','rs','1','rs','1','rs','1','rs'),
             array('rs','1','rs','1','rs','1','rs','1'),
             array('1','rs','1','rs','1','rs','1','rs'),
             array('rs','bs','rs','bs','rs','bs','rs','bs'),
             array('bs','rs','bs','rs','bs','rs','bs','rs'),
             array('2','bs','2','bs','2','bs','2','bs'),
             array('bs','2','bs','2','bs','2','bs','2'),
             array('2','bs','2','bs','2','bs','2','bs')
              );
```

1 = black pieces
2 = red pieces
rs = red square
bs = black square

this code parse the input of a player : example FROM F2 into (0,0) coordinates

```
function parseSquareFrom($square) {
    if (strlen($square) != 2) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $coords = array(ord('A') - ord($square[0]), $square[1] - 1);

    // Perform bounds-checking.
    if ($coords[0] < 0 || $coords[0] > 7 || $coords[1] < 0 || $coords[1] > 7) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return $coords;
}
```

I have repeated the same function for the TO input ( to where the player wants to move the piece

my question is this next code a valid way to move with the functions above

```
    $board[$coords1[0]-1][$coords1[1]+1] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]];
    $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]] = 0;

    //eating action
    $board[$coords1[0]][$coords1[1]] = 0;
    $board[$coords1[0]-2][$coords1[1]+2] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]];

$way = ($_POST['way'] === 'up')? 1:-1;

$way = ($_POST['way'] === 'down')? -1:+1;



    //if player is 'up' then the value of $way is 1 so
      $board[$x+(-1*$way)][$y+(1*$way)] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // position 2,2 becomes 1,3
   //if player is not 'up' then the value of $way is -1 so
      $board[$x+(-1*$way)][$y+(1*$way)] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // position 2,2 becomes 3,1
```

I plan to have a function to update the tile movements in the screen so the piece moves as the it highlights the piece as is moving to the next square

this is using serialize into file to hold start positions, movements, kings and queens positions

Comment: Agreed. You accept an answer by clicking on the arrow under the score and the arrows at the left of the answer. You can only do this for one answer.  You can also vote for those answers you considered useful by clicking on the up-arrow next to the answer.

Comment: Ok i agree with i haven't up voting anyone i am sorry for that but i have repeatedly said thanks and I apologize to everyone i irritated with this questions

Comment: how would i update the board when there is movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `$coords` is a `$_POST` variable like a suggested on the first part of this question. If that's the case, the first part of your code is correct:

```
$board[$coords1[0]-1][$coords1[1]+1] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]];
$board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]] = 0;
```

This moves a piece diagonally one step up-right in the board.
The second part on the other hand skips the actual 'eating' action. Unless, the location specified by the user is the one where the enemy piece is. In which case you code would work.

---

As for the bound-checking you do, you're not being bullet-proof since adding 2 in the eating move, while a piece is next to a border would result in your code trying to place the piece out of the board. So you could check bounds, depending on the move, so if the move is a standard diagonal one, you should check that the ending position is within the limits, not the starting one since you are assuming that piece is in a correct position before.

Comment: yes $_POST will be from variable $square will be user input into the From form into that function

Comment: the user point of view you mean the $way variable which looks at which player is moving from the top to bottom and which player is moving from the bottom to the top yes i will try to implement that code after i get this one working

Comment: @hgbso: Yes, I mean the `$way` variable I suggested, I'm glad you're considering it.

Comment: but this the thing there a checkers.html where the users input their names ::::         Player 1 Name:<input type="text" name="p1name"/><br />
        Player 2 Name:<input type="text" name="p2name" /><br /> do put values in there

Comment: add a hidden input for each player's form that contains the value of the `$way` var. For example `<input type='hidden' id='way' value='down'/>`

Comment: <input type="text" name="p1name" type ="hidden" id="way" value="down/> or <input type="hidden" id="way" value="down/>

Comment: you code that i am using i have put it in a function to handle movement with the parse functions for : FROM and TO do i add the $coords into the values of the $way variable

Comment: in this part -- $way = ($_POST['player'] === 'up')? 1:-1; -- what do i put in where it says 'player' or do i leave it like that

Comment: `$way = ($_POST['way'] === 'up')? 1:-1;`

Comment: I should use if statements with the $way variable

Comment: No, you shouldn't. The code I gave you replaces the `if statements` it does the following. "Asign a value to `$way`, if the post variable is 'up' asign it a 1, if not, asign it a -1"

Comment: the black and red pieces have been mapped i know there are array functions where you can shift or push will those work for updating the board

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few issues

```
$board[$coords1[0]-1][$coords1[1]+1] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]];
```

if $coords[1] == 7 (which appears to be allowed) then $coords[1]+1 == 8 which is out of bounds.  Let alone the coords +/- 2 we see later.

You probably don't want that 'bs'/'rs' in your storage, all of that can be inferred.

```
$getSquareColor = function($x,$y){return ($x+$y)/2 == 1 ? 'red' : 'black';}  //or better yet, const or enum


function getSquareColor($x, $y)  //alternatively
{
    if ( ($x+$y) % 2 == 0) return 'black';
    else return 'red';
}
```

ps - if you drop those dollar signs the function is just as good in javascript

Comment: 'bs', 'rs' are the values of images for black and red square mapped into the board array from another array called pieces just like the black and red pieces or is there another way to create a board display that have a checkered pattern of red and black squares

Comment: i get how that's convenient for the images, but it makes recording the moves a little more complicated.  i guess you could go either way.  does your client side get the array or are you rendering everything thru php and just sending image?  giving the client side the array would let you disallow the user from selecting invalid moves without sending a request, so thats good

Comment: im trying to use serialize to hold the positions in a text file

Comment: why text file?  i dont see the need for file i/o.  cant you give it to javascript as a json or something?  or to a template engine as is?

Comment: or is text file for history?  i guess thats not an awful idea but you're really gonna have one after every move?

Comment: im using json encode with serialize to text file and i don't know any javascript some c++, c# and php

Comment: so you plan to make the state stick between page requests with the text file? that would work, but you'd probably rather just pass the state back and forth from your server-side and client.  the client can benefit from having the state in other ways, such as enforcing valid moves.

Comment: nah thats overkill, and doesn't even lend itself well to the design.  MAYBE for incomplete games lasting longer than a session.

Comment: I know theres other languages that coould help with this like javascript like you said and ajax but i just started learning PHP a month ago

Comment: you'll have a hard time doing everything on the server with PHP, id look into javascript

Comment: your function is inferring the the red and black values into the $x and $y

Comment: it lacked a comparison, but what do you mean by inferring?  the coordinates do determine the color of a square

Comment: this part $coords[1]+1 == 8 should be $coords[1]+0 == 8

Comment: huh?  that wasnt code, that was just me explaining that when $coords[1] is 7 you are going to go out of bounds when you add 1 (or 2) to it.  it is exactly as i intended to say

Comment: ok sorry my bad but i do need to change that code so it go out of bounds

Comment: you've got a lot of things to consider, but yes you do need to check bounds in some other/different/additional way. its kind of growing out of this question and i cant stick around.  sorry, good luck!    PS - thanks for showing me 'ord', ive never used it

Comment: no problem thank you for the help for ord part someone showed it to me in another one of my posts --- the ord() function takes a string and returns the equivalent ASCII value

Comment: would a session help in passing the state back and forth or is that impossible for PHP

Comment: nothing wrong with that.  PHP uses session no better or worse than any other language, its not a feature of any languag per se

Comment: do i give each new session an id specific to that session so if a new game starts a new session while the last session sends the score who won who lost | to the mysql table for score keeping then that session is destroyed afterwards